# OIDC Authorization Code flow /token response

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, access-token

Is it possible for /token endpoint to just return id_token and not access_token in case of authorization code flow? I could not find anything mentioned around this in OIDC spec the way I read it. I would appreciate and pointers in documentation around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to section 3.1.3.3 in the [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) it says

*After receiving and validating a valid and authorized Token Request from the Client, the Authorization Server returns a successful response that includes an ID Token and an Access Token.*

So I guess you always gets both, but its up to you to ignore the tokens you don't care about.